# Run Upon PyAutoGUI Fail Safe

Tags: python, pyautogui

Put simply, I'm trying to figure out how to run some code when the PyAutoGUI failsafe executes. I've tried searching this problem many times and can't figure out a way to do it.

This is what I want:

1. Move mouse to corner and provoke failsafe.
2. Right before program ends from fail safe, runs line of code.
3. Program completely closes.

Answer (score 1):

The `pyautogui.FailSafeException` is raised when the mouse is moved to the upper left corner (x,y of 0, 0). You could catch this exception and run code from there:

import pyautogui
import sys

```
while True:
    try:
        pyautogui.moveTo() # Any PyAutoGUI (without side effects) call will do here.
    except pyautogui.FailSafeException:
        print('Running code before exiting.') # Your code here.
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: Well I don't want to disable it, I just want a way to run some code right before it raises fail safe

Comment: You could disable it with `pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False` and then run that bit of code, and then sel `pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True` immediately after. Or, just put the call in a try/except block.

Comment: But if fail safe is off then pyautogui doesn't know if you put your mouse in the corner

Comment: Ah, yes. Sorry, I misunderstood. But you can put the last PyAutoGUI call in a try/except block, and then have the code in the except block run and then exit. I've updated my answer.